# Controlling Parsing Step Size with papaparse.js for Large Files

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I am working with the `papaparse.js` library to parse a very large file. I want to control the parsing step size, for instance, parsing only every 100th row to optimize performance. However, using `step=100` doesn't seem to work as expected. Can someone guide me on the correct way to control the parsing step size in `papaparse.js` when dealing with large files?

```
Papa.parse(fileName, {
  download: true,
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  //step:100,  // <- does not work
  complete: (results) => {
    onDataParsed(results.data);
  },
  error: (error) => {
    console.error(`Error parsing CSV ${fileName}:`, error);
  }
});
```